# Error message in QGIS using Timemanager

Tags: qgis, csv, timemanager

I am using QGIS version 2.14.0 (Essen) and have dowloaded the latest version of the Time Manager plugin in order to do some spatial-temporal analysis.

I have imported a csv file into QGIS and made a join wih a shapefile in order to import all the time data on the shapefile. However, when I use this shapefile in Time Manager, it recognises the data as the start date appears in the player time frame, but the video and animation do not load. The following error message appears (in french as I am using it in french):

> *Couche Impétrants_Verzoekers_p: OGR [3] erreur 1: "programmes_Date debut" not recognised as an available field.*

Here is the data I am using in these two columns I imported from a csv file. Anybody know what is wrong?

```
Date debut              Date fin
2016-05-02 00:00:00 2018-09-30 00:00:00
2016-01-04 00:00:00 2018-12-10 00:00:00
2015-09-01 00:00:00 2017-12-31 00:00:00
2016-04-25 00:00:00 2017-12-15 00:00:00
2016-03-01 00:00:00 2018-03-30 00:00:00
2016-01-04 00:00:00 2017-12-29 00:00:00
```

Comment: Your date fields are probably in the wrong format as you seem to be using `YYYY-MM-YYYY hh-mm-ss`. Are you supposed to have the year mentioned twice? `YYYY-MM-DD hh-mm-ss` should work.

Comment: Sorry y fault i put in the wrong data. I just edited the question and added the correct data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can use **Joined** fields for the *Start* and *End* times. I also tested this and received the same error. This has already been recognised as a [feature request](https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/issues/148).

A workaround would be to save your joined shapefile as a **new shapefile** which will contain all the joined attributes and then add this shapefile to the Time Manager plugin.

Comment: @philippe - Most welcome! Glad it works =)

Comment: I guess they should have mentionned it somewhere! I'm sure many people have had this problem

Comment: @philippe - Edited post to include the GitHub feature request page in which this issue has been identified ;)

Comment: thanks, just was a bit frustrating as I've been trying for a couple of days to get it to work when the solution was quite simple (thought first of all my date format was wrong then thought some charcaters were not accepted....)

Comment: @philippe - Don't worry, this sort of thing happens to all of us all the time!